# ASP.NET Bootstrap Modal

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am quite new to ASP.NET so forgive me if I have the functionality wrong.

I am working with Bootstrap and have a button within a tab and UpdatePanel which fires a Modal.

The Modal sits behind the screen and blacks out and I can't quite work out why.

If I take the UpdatePanel out, it works. I need the UpdatePanel because it is in a tab with an action CheckBox which without the UpdatePanel sends the user back to the first tab.

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="neworder">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up_New_Order" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cb_Auto_Fill" runat="server" Text="Auto fill last order" CssClass="checkbox" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="cb_Auto_Fill_CheckedChanged"></asp:CheckBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">

                <!-- New Order -->
                <asp:panel class="row form-group has-feedback" id="Panel2" runat="server">
                    <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Ordered By</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="tb_Ordered_By" placeholder="Customer name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </asp:panel>

                <asp:panel class="row form-group has-feedback" id="Panel5" runat="server">
                    <label for="inputSubject" class="col-lg-4 control-label">PO No/Agency</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="tb_Po_Number" placeholder="PO No/Agency Ref" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </asp:panel>

                <asp:panel class="row form-group has-feedback" id="Panel13" runat="server">
                    <label for="inputSubject" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Payment Type</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Payment_Type" runat="server" CssClass="form-control dropdown"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                </asp:panel>  

                <asp:panel class="row form-group has-feedback" id="Panel14" runat="server" Visible="false">
                    <label for="inputSubject" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Upload</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <input  type="file" 
                                style="visibility:hidden; width: 1px;height:1px" 
                                id='${multipartFilePath}' name='${multipartFilePath}'  
                                onchange="$(this).parent().find('span').html($(this).val().replace('C:\\fakepath\\', ''))"  /> <!-- Chrome security returns 'C:\fakepath\'  -->
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Upload File.." onclick="$(this).parent().find('input[type=file]').click();"/> <!-- on button click fire the file click event -->
                        &nbsp;
                        <span  class="badge badge-important" ></span>
                    </div>
                </asp:panel> 


                <asp:panel class="row form-group has-feedback" id="Panel11" runat="server">
                    <label for="inputSubject" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Order Notes</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <asp:TextBox id="tb_Order_Notes" cssClass="form-control" TextMode="multiline" Columns="50" Rows="3" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                </asp:panel>   

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">

            <!-- New Order -->
            <asp:panel class="row form-group has-feedback" id="Panel7" runat="server">
                <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Copy Contact</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="tb_Copy_Contact" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </asp:panel>

            <asp:panel class="row form-group has-feedback" id="Panel8" runat="server">
                <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Copy Supply</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="tb_Copy_Supply" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </asp:panel>

            <asp:panel class="row form-group has-feedback" id="Panel9" runat="server">
                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Copy Tel</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="tb_Copy_Tel" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </asp:panel>

            <asp:panel class="row form-group has-feedback" id="Panel10" runat="server">
                <label for="inputSubject" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Copy Email</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="tb_Copy_Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </asp:panel>
            <div class="row form-group">

            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <asp:Button Text="Create Order" ID="btn_Create_Order" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block" OnClick="btn_Create_Order_Click" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

The modal sits just above my closing tag for Content and I call it with:

```
protected void btn_Create_Order_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblModalTitle.Text = "Modal Title";
    lblModalBody.Text = "Modal Body.";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "myModal", "$('#myModal').modal().appendTo('body');", true);
    upModal.Update();

    //pnlAlertBox.Visible = true;
}
```

Here is the modal (I am reusing it so I know it does work).

```
<!-- Bootstrap Modal Dialog -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upModal" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title"><asp:Label ID="lblModalTitle" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblModalBody" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would help if you could replicate the issue using [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: I did try, but couldn't get it to work with the ASP tags.

Comment: why do you append the modal to body. In your button click event you must show the modal and it should work. So `$('#myModal').modal('show');`. Also if you dont like this you can add OnClientClick event to your Create_Order button like this `OnClientClick=$('#myModal').modal('show');return false;`

Comment: I appended it to body after looking at another solution. I tried your solution but still have the same problem: http://imgur.com/SEBZS5z This is after amending the button to look like: `<asp:Button Text="Create Order" ID="btn_Create_Order" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block" OnClientClick="$('#myModal').modal('show');return false;" runat="server" />`

Comment: try put your modal in `<div class="container row form-horizontal"></div>` outside the `<div class="tab-pane fade" id="neworder"></div>`

Comment: Nope same problem. Literally, if I remove the ContentTemplate and UpdatePanel it works, but I need them in due to the way I'm processing the form. If I don't do it that way, when the button is pressed, it reverts back to #tab1 while it needs to be in #tab3 if that makes sense?

Comment: You can avoid the update panel by using jquery to setup your modal, set the header and body text etc. you can also use ajax to extract db data if you want etc

Comment: @user3004160 which update panel do you remove to make it work? the one in the modal itself or the one where the button is?

Comment: The first one #up_New_Order

Comment: @user3004160 if you move your update panel from `<div class=modal-dialog></div>' to `<div class=modal-body></div>` it should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107717/discussion-between-user3004160-and-shareyourknowledge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code in my sample project and the bootstrap modal works correctly. I am using jquery 2.1.3

It could be that the jquery version you are using is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help and in private chat. It was indeed the version of jQuery.